# Clearing user input - New Remote Connection Window MAC OSX

Tags: ssh

I was using Terminal.app to to use the ssh command and I opened the "New Remote Connection" window. There is this long text box under the "user" box that displays the ssh ... commands that were entered. How do I clear my input? It just displays all of my server names that were entered? The delete doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can clear the *New Remote Connection* history (which is shown in the dropbox that you mentioned) by typing the following in an active Terminal window:

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal PreviousCommands '()'
```

Then, quit and restart Terminal and the history should be empty.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, but it isn't working. I still see the server names. I exactly followed what you said.

Comment: I apologize! It is working fine. Thanks so much!! :-)

Comment: Be sure to quit Terminal and open it again to see the changes.